# Calculate the sum of the following series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to calculate this series :

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!}$$

This is what I've done, and for some reason its wrong.

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!}=$$

$$\frac{x}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}=$$
$$\frac{x}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^kk!}=$$
$$\frac{x}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(\frac{x}{2})^k}{k!}=$$
$$\frac{x}{2}e^{\frac{x}{2}}$$

I don't understand what's wrong with my answer? Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The first one isn't equal to the second one.

Comment: @Aran Komatsuzaki Oh, I should make it $k-1$ instand of $k+1$ right?

Comment: He's right, $x^k=x\cdot x^{k-1}$ not $x\cdot x^{k+1}$.

Comment: Also,in the end,the taylor expansion of e starts from 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{2^k(k+1)!}=\frac{2}{x}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}=\frac{2}{x}\left(e^{x/2}-1\right).$$

Comment: Can you explain how did you managed to reach to $\frac{2}{x}\left(e^{x/2}-1\right)$ This is what I did start with the 2nd expression.
$$\frac{2}{x}\sum_{k=0}\frac{x^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}=\frac{2}{x}\sum_{k=1}\frac{x^{k}}{2^{k}(k)!}=\frac{2}{x}e^{\frac{x}{2}}$$

Comment: @JaVaPG: $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{2^k k!}=e^{x/2}$$ and you just need to subtract the $k=0$ term.

Comment: You'r right I didn't notice that forumula start from $k=0$ however if I subtract I get $$\frac{2}{x}\sum_{k=0}\frac{‌​x^{k-1}}{2^{k-1}(k-1)!}$$ And then I cannot use the formula any ideas?

Comment: @JaVaPG: again: $$\frac{2}{x}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}=\frac{2}{x}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^k}{2^k k!}=\frac{2}{x}\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{2^k k!}-1\right)=\frac{2}{x}\left(e^{x/2}-1\right).$$ At the beginning you have an entire function, hence you will have an entire function at the end.